# Jakarta EE - Interceptors run only when invoked on class but not on methods

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, crud, interceptor, java-ee-8

My final intent is to have an interceptor that is invoked on certain methods and apply bean validation on the inputs.

My business services provide CRUD capabilities and, in order to do so, I have a simple hierarchy where I group CRUD methods in interfaces/abstract classes.

When I try to add an interceptor on some of these inherited CRUD methods, it is not invoked. If I apply the same to the whole business service class it is instead running. This is not accepted solution because it will run for all methods of the class while I want to run it only for some of them.

Why is this happening?

Example:

Business service and where the interceptor should run, on method `create`

```
@Stateless
public class UserManagementServiceImpl implements UserManagementService {

    @Override
    @Interceptors(SpecificationValidator.class)
    public User create(UserSpec spec) { } 

}
```

Interceptor:

```
@Interceptor
public class SpecificationValidator {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Intercepted: " + ctx.getMethod() );
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

Class hierarchy is

```
@Stateless
public class UserManagementServiceImpl implements UserManagementService {
...
}
```

```
public interface UserManagementService<User,UserSpec> extends ManagementService<D,S> {

}
```

```
public interface ManagementService<D,S> {

    D create(S specification) throws AlreadyExistsException;

}
```

With this setup the interceptor is not invoked.

If instead I annotate my final business bean, the interceptor is invoked.

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpecificationValidator.class)
public class UserManagementServiceImpl implements UserManagementService {

    @Override
    public User create(UserSpec spec) { }
```

NOTE: I also tried by defining an interceptor binding annotation. The result is the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: uops yes..it was just a tzpo...thanks for spotting!

Comment: I have cleaned it up.

Comment: My comments will self-destruct shorly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interceptor method not called with interceptor binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076586/interceptor-method-not-called-with-interceptor-binding)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930897/interceptor-not-working-at-method-level-in-a-servlet

Comment: The problem is neither related to add interceptors to the bean.xml (I am using java ee 8) nor the priority to be set. It seems to rely on the specific hierarchy I have in place for my CRUD Services. If the EJB is injected through an interface, the interface must declare the methods to be intercepted otherwise they are not found.